# How can I add my website to DMOZ?

Tags: dmoz

I have a new website that I tried to list in DMOZ, but as of now it's still not listed.

Please tell me what I have to do so that my website will get listed in DMOZ.

Comment: We really only have 11 other questions here that just mention [DMOZ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=dmoz+is%3Aquestion). This [question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/is-dmoz-still-active) has some more answers as to why.

Comment: It isn't possible for muggle sites to get listed on DMOZ. This became apparent to me several years ago after thousands of fruitless hours.

Answer (score 10):

All you can do is submit it. There is no way to guarantee that it will get listed. Listing depends on:

1. Whether there is an editor for your category
2. Whether they are active
3. Whether they decide to approve your site

DMOZ was a mess not too long ago and is probably worse now that its importance and relevancy has declined severely. I wouldn't have expectations that your site will be listed soon or at all.

Important: Do **NOT** resubmit your site to the same or any other category. Doing so only causes your site to be rejected or further pushes you down in the queue.

Comment: D-who? O that thing. Directories were, the world moved on, now they aren't... It's a decade too late to get any use out of DMOZ. I remember working hard to get listed, about 5 years later, it had already started to steamily compost.