# How long does it take to be approved to the Dmoz directory?

Tags: seo, directory-listing, dmoz

In directories Dmoz has special preference for directory listing.

I had submitted 60 days back in dmoz still it not displaying my site, what is the problem with my site or still I have to wait?

Comment: DMoz is dead from many years now. You will most probably never see your site in this directory. You can forget it.

Comment: See [Is DMOZ still active?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/18500/28169). You will get better idea about DMOZ.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar OP has already added his site to Dmoz. He is asking about the time it takes for approval.

Comment: @Wexford Yes. Check [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67558/how-can-i-add-my-website-to-dmoz) question. OP of that question stated that "I have a new website that I tried to list in DMOZ, but as of now it's still not listed." What's the meaning of this statement? According to me he submitted his site but it was not listed in Dmoz which looks same as this question.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar You're right. The question titles on both submissions should be rephrased though.

Comment: It's funny that so many SEO's still suggest dMOZ...it's a clear indicator that their tactics are obsolete. The truth is that your site won't get accepted. And even if it is accepted, dMOZ will be down about a year from now (RIP). Spend your time with credible business directories and the big 5 social networks instead.

Answer (score 1):

Getting listed in the Dmoz directory can take a very long time. 60 days is nothing. In most cases, it can take up to one or two years (assuming you actually get approved). Personally speaking, I don't think that you should worry about it too much. Dmoz has lost its importance over the years and directories are a weak form of link building in this day and age. Submit the site and focus on other SEO efforts.

Answer (score 1):

At one point [I was very active at Dmoz as an editor](http://www.dmoz.org/public/profile?editor=deadsea).  I no let my account lapse and I am no longer active there.  In fact, most editors have left, so not many sites get approved anymore.

If you still want to get listed, you will need to find a small category with an active editor where your site actually fits.    Most categories have an incoming queue of dozens if not hundreds of sites that nobody is looking at.   The only chance you have of getting listed is to find a small category where the editor actually keeps up with the flood of submissions.

Of course, even then if that editor feels that your submission is not a great fit for that category, they will move it to a different category where it may never get reviewed.

Submitting to a larger category is a waste of time.   Anything within two levels from the top is not going to have editors that ever look at it.

When submitting your site, make it easy for the editor:

- Only submit your home page.
- Write a description of your site that is a full sentence.
- A list of what your site does is appropriate for your description.
- Avoid "marketing speak" like "visit now".
- Avoid superlatives like "best".
- Avoid the phrase "and more".
- Make sure the description differentiates your site from the other sites that are already listed.